# Login page images with CSS url's not displayed

Tags: asp.net, css, authentication

Okay, I am stumped on this one and need some quick help.

I have an ASP.NET application using Forms authentication.  In my Login.aspx page, I use several images in the background for visual affect.  The url's are being set using CSS styles that are defined in the file (not in a theme et al).  All of the images are located in an Images folder under the root level of the website.  There is a separate web.config in the Images folder allowing all users access.

The issue I'm running into is getting the images to resolve consistently in the development environment and production environment.  What I learned (and have no control over) is that the site is deployed to a sub-site in production while we are using the Cassini web server in Visual Studio for development.  As a result, starting each path with a backslash (/) doesn't work in production (although it works fine in development). Removing the backslash breaks the dev environment.

Currently, I have the CSS defined similar to:

```
#banner
{
    background: transparent url('Images/plainBlueHeader2.png') no-repeat 20% 0;
    height: 70px;
    top: 21px;
    left: 3px;
}
```

This doesn't work in Development but it works in our QA and Production environments.

To make matters worse, this was apparently working fine and less knowledgable co-workers are blaming some recent additions to the application where we added several new pages in a sub-folder.  I should mention that prior to this ALL pages were at the site root.

Not sure what else I can share so please ask whatever questions are needed to help come up with a solution.

**UPDATE:**
It turns out that one of the three images IS showing up properly in all environments.  The one associated with the BODY element is working but the others, one using the ID as shown in the example above and the other through a CSS class, are not.

**UPDATE:**
Here is the code for my web page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="Login" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
  <title>Login</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body { background:#fff url('Images/bodyBackBlue.png') repeat-x;font-size:11px;font-family:Sans-Serif; }

    #wrapper { width:990px;margin-top:30px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;position:relative; }

    #bannerwrapper { width:990px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;position:relative; }

    #banner { background:transparent url('Images/plainBlueHeader2.png') no-repeat 20% 0;height:70px;top:21px;left:3px; }

    .logo { float:left;text-decoration:none;margin-left:30px;margin-top:29px; }

    .user-greeting { background-image:none;margin:8px 100px;color:#fff;float:right;font-weight:bold; }

    .warningWrapper { float:none;font-family:Sans-Serif;font-size:small;margin-left:20px; }

    #infowrapper { margin:3px 3px 3px 3px;width:68%;border-left:solid 1px #00629b; }

    #rightColumnWrapper { margin:3px 13px 3px 3px;width:28%;float:right; }

    #loginwrapper { height:220px;border-left:solid 1px #00629b;margin-bottom:20px; }

    #noticewrapper { height:100px;border-top:1px solid #00629b;margin-bottom:20px; } 

    .contentTopper { overflow:hidden;position:static;background:transparent URL('Images/portlet_topper_back.png') left repeat-x;height:23px;min-height:23px; }

    .contentTitle { float:left;color:#fff;font-weight:bold;font-size:15px;padding-top:2px;padding-left:4px; }

    .contentleft { padding:20px 5px 5px 8px;float:left;width:400px; }

    .contentRight { float:right;padding:30px 20px 10px 10px; }

    .content { padding-left:5px; }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="bannerwrapper">
    <div id="banner">
      <span class="logo"><img id="LogoImage" src="Images/LogoLarge.jpg" height="40px" width="105px"/></span>
      <span class="user-greeting">Welcome!</span>
    </div>
  </div>        
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="rightColumnWrapper">
      <div id="loginwrapper">
        <div class="contentTopper"> 
          <span class="contentTitle"> Sign In </span>
        </div>
        <div class="content">        
          <form id="Login" runat="server">
            <asp:Panel ID="PanelLogin" runat="server">
              <table>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="LabelUserName" runat="server">User name:</asp:Label>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td width="150">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" runat="server" Height="20px"></asp:TextBox>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="LabelPassword" runat="server">Password:</asp:Label>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>                                
                  <td width="150">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Height="20px" Width="100%" ></asp:TextBox><br />
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>                                
                  <td width="80" style="padding: 5px">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" EnableTheming="true" Text="Sign In" OnClick="btnLogin_Click"></asp:Button><br />
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              <asp:Label ID="errorLabel" runat="server" ForeColor="#ff3300"></asp:Label><br />
            </asp:Panel>
          </form>
        </div>                
      </div>
      <div id="noticewrapper">
        <div class="contentTopper"> 
          <span class="contentTitle"> Special Notice </span>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          <ul>
            <li>abc</li>
          </ul>               
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="infowrapper">
      <div class="contentTopper"> 
        <span class="contentTitle"> Welcome </span>
      </div>
      <div class="contentleft">
        <p><span style="font-size: small"><b>abc</b></span></p>
        <p>abc</p>
        <p><b>abc</b>abc</p>
        <p><b>abc</b>abc</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="contentRight">
        <img class="contentRight" id="LogoImage2" src="Images/LogoLarge.jpg" height="79px" width="199px"/> 
        <p style="text-align: center">abc</p>
      </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="warningWrapper">
      <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ForeColor="#FF0000" ></asp:Label>        
      <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" ForeColor="#FF0000" Visible="false" Text="abc"></asp:Label>
      <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" ForeColor="#FF0000" Visible="false" Text="abc"></asp:Label>
      <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" ForeColor="#993300" Visible="false" Text="abc"></asp:Label>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the syntax, check the path

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After all the back-and-forth discussion, I found this post: [ASP.NET theme not rendering correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315780/asp-net-theme-not-rendering-correctly).  I now realize that the problem was due to the authorization rules Cassini enforces on the App_Themes folder.  Because I am using Forms authentication, the Login.aspx page is being displayed to unauthenticated users and Cassini wasn't allowing the page to access anything in App_Themes.  For some reason, this was blocking the rest of the CSS styles from getting applied, I guess.

Nevertheless, the ultimate solution was to add the following into my web.config:

```
  <location path="App_Themes">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

I'd like to thank @matt_ashbury for the guidance - I couldn't have found a solution without your help!

Comment: This was a great answer, and helped me correct the same issue on an app i inherited and have working on a server, but not on my dev box for the login screen. I wish there was a way to push these up  to the front of google!

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
#banner
{
    background: transparent url('<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Images/plainBlueHeader2.png") %>') no-repeat 20% 0;
}
```

it's safer than using .. as your image location could be moved easily

Comment: Two problems with this solution. One, I get an exception - but I could have mistyped something. Nevertheless, using the tilde (~) isn't the solution as that tells the runtime that the path is relative to the site root. In development, this is fine since the path is something like http://localhost:1234/Login.aspx. In production it doesn't work because the application is running in a folder beneath the root site, like http://server/root/Login.aspx. (BTW, the Images folder is in the same folder as Login.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
url(./Images/plainBlueHeader2.png)
```

Comment: Just out of interest, if you swap the image you use in the body tag with the one in the #banner, is the image still displayed or does this (plainBlueHeader.png) now work for the body?

Comment: Interesting. Yes, when I switch the images, the BODY tag still renders correctly (with plainBlueHeader2.png) and the original image does not show for #banner.

Comment: Could you post the CSS for the body tag please?

Comment: Also what tag has the banner id (div, span, etc.)?

Comment: <div id="bannerwrapper"> <div id="banner"> <span class="logo"> <img id="LogoImage" src="Images/LogoLarge.jpg" height="40px" width="105px" /> </span> </div> </div> The inner image always resoves as well.  (I should mention that I didn't write this code but have been assigned to fix it. Classic.)

Comment: Okay, I would assume that the problem isn't the image folder path and it's some other property in the CSS. Could you paste the CSS file to pastie.org?

Comment: Unfortunately that site is blocked by my company's websense.  you are on to something.  I move the #banner CSS to before the BODY style and it renders correctly and BODY does not!

Comment: Can you check that URL for me please. I am getting a message to say the code isn't recognised.

Comment: Yea, I get an error everytime I try to post.  Is there a trick?

Comment: Okay, funny how these things come together. The only HTML element that had 'runat=server' is the <head> element. I remove that and get an exception because the site is using themes. I put it back and take out the theme attribute from the <pages> element in the web.config and the page renders correctly!!! This means that the problem is related to using themes and having the theme CSS. But, there are no name conflicts (either ID or class) in the theme CSS so I don't know why it would be causing a problem. Any ideas?

Comment: It appears that none of the class or named (ID) styles are resolving when the theme is enabled. I also tried moving the styles into the theme CSS file and NONE of them get applied.  Obviously something to do with the Login file and theming.

Comment: I think this now be a question for the ASP section as it outside of my skillset. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If - as I imagine - you have a folder css at the same level of images folder then you could also write

```
background: transparent url(../Images/plainBlueHeader2.png) no-repeat 20% 0;
```

You can referer to the images using relative paths
(aside, you can also avoid trailing quotes).

Comment: Unfortunately, the Images folder is at the same level as my Login.aspx page so using ../ will force the runtime to try and climb up the folder hierarchy to find Images which is not where it's located in either environment.